# Show that the map $(z,w) \mapsto (z^{am} w^{bn}, z^{cm} w^{dn})$ is a covering map.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Show that the map $f : S^1 \times S^1 \longrightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ defined by $(z,w) \mapsto (z^{am} w^{bn}, z^{cm} w^{dn})$ is a covering map of degree $mn$ where $ad - bc = 1$ and $a,b,c,d,m,n \in \mathbb Z.$

Our instructor says that it can be written as a composition of covering maps of finite degree and hence it's a covering map. But I can't see how can it be written as composition of covering maps.

Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated. Thanks for investing your valuable time on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define maps $\phi, \psi  : S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1$ by
$$\phi(z,w) = (z^n,w^m), $$
$$\psi(u,v) = (u^av^b,u^cv^d) .$$
Clearly $f = \psi \circ \phi$.

The maps $\omega_k : S^1 \to S^1, \omega_k(z)= z^k$, are covering maps of degree $p$. We have $\phi =  \omega_n  \times \omega_m$. We now invoke the following

**Theorem.** Let $p : \tilde X \to X$ and $q : \tilde Y \to Y$ be covering maps. Them $p \times q$ is a covering map. If $\deg p = n$ and $\deg q = m$, then $\deg p \times q = nm$.

This is well-known and the proof is very easy.

We conclude that $\phi$ is a covering map of degree $mn$.

In order that the claim in your question be true, $\psi$ should be a covering map of degree $1$. But such maps are *homeomorphisms*. This heuristic consideration shows that we should prove that $\psi$ is a homeomorphism.

Given a $(2 \times 2)$-matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ with entries in $\mathbb Z$, let us define
$$A^* : S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1, A^*(u,v) = (u^av^b,u^cv^d) .$$

Clearly the unit matrix $E$ gives
$$ E^* = id \tag{1} .$$
Let us next show that for $B = \begin{pmatrix} e & f \\ g & h \end{pmatrix}$ one has
$$(A \cdot B)^* = A^* \circ B^* \tag{2} .$$

We have $A \cdot B = \begin{pmatrix} a e + b g & a f + b h \\ c e + d g &  c f + d h \end{pmatrix}$, thus
$$(A \cdot B)^*(u,v) = (u^{a e + b g} v^{a f + b h}, u^{c e + d g }v^{c f + d h}) ,$$

$$A^*(B^*(u,v)) = A^*(u^ev^f,u^gv^h) = ((u^ev^f)^{a}(u^gv^h)^{b}, (u^ev^f)^{c}(u^gv^h)^{d}) \\= (u^{e a} v^{f a} u^{g b} v^{h b},u^{e c} v^{f c} u^{g d} v^{h d}) = (u^{e a + g b}v^{f a + h b},u^{e c + g d}v^{f c + h d}) .$$

This proves $(2)$.

Formulae $(1)$ and $(2)$ show that if $A$ is invertible and $A^{-1}$ has all entries in $\mathbb Z$, then $A^*$ is a homeomorphism.

$\det A = ad - bc \ne 0$ means that $A$ is invertible as a real metrix. But we even have $\det A = 1$ which implies that $A^{-1}$ has  all entries in $\mathbb Z$.

Since $\psi = A^*$, we are finished.

**Update:**

That $A^{-1}$ has integer entries follows from

**Lemma.** Let $A$ be an $(n \times n)$-matrix with entries in $\mathbb Z$. Then $A$ has an inverse $A^{-1}$ with entries in $\mathbb Z$ if and only if $\det A =  \pm 1$.

*Proof.* 1. For all matrices $A, B$ with entries in $\mathbb R$ we have $\det A \cdot B = \det A  \cdot \det B$. If both $A, B$ have entries in $\mathbb Z$, then also $\det A, \det B \in \mathbb Z$.

1. Assume that $A$ has entries in   $\mathbb Z$ and has an inverse $A^{-1}$ with entries in   $\mathbb Z$. Then $$1 = \det E = \det A \cdot A^{-1} = \det A \cdot \det A^{-1} \tag{3}.$$ Since both $\det A, \det A^{-1} \in \mathbb Z$, $(3)$ can only be satisfied when $\det A = \det A^{-1} = 1$ or $\det A = \det A^{-1} = -1$.
2. Assume that $A$ has entries in $\mathbb Z$ and has $\det A = \pm 1$. Then $A$ is invertible as a real matrix. It inverse is given by
   $$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A} \left(-1)^{i+j} A_{ij}\right)^T \tag{4}$$
   where the $A_{ij}$ are the minors of $A$ and $^T$ denotes transposition. The minors are the determinants of the $((n-1) \times (n-1))$-submatrices of $A$ obtained by deleting the $i$-th row and $j$-th column. If $A$ has entries in $\mathbb Z$  then all $A_{ij} \in \mathbb Z$ and therefore $A^{-1}$ has entries in $\mathbb Z$ since $\det A =  \pm 1$.

Comment: $\det A = 1$ doesn't necessarily imply all the entries of $A^{-1}$ are integers. Simply consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} \frac 1 2  & 0 \\0&2 \end{pmatrix}.$ If $A$ is any invertible matrix with integer entries then it is necessarily true that the entries of $A^{-1}$ are also integers. That's because if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with integer entries then all it's $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ minors should also be integers and consequently $A^{-1}$ is a matrix with integer entries as well. Determinant has nothing to do with it. So your penultimate paragraph doesn't make sense to me. Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa We start with a matrix having integer entries. Hence its inverse also has integer entries if the determinant is $1$. You have to devide the "minor-matrix" by $\det A$. Consider any diagonal matrix whose entries are $> 1$.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I forgot the fact that I need to divide the minor matrix by $\det A$ in order to get $A^{-1}.$

Comment: Thanks for this detailed solution and for the update as well.  Can you clarify the meaning of $\bar A$ as well as $\bar a$ etc.?  All I can think is conjugate, except that the values are all assumed to be integers. Am I missing something or are you just covering a more general case and that $a\bar a$ here is just $a^2$.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 It is any other matrix. Its entries are $\bar a$ etc. Perhaps I should have named it $B$ with entries $e$ etc. But I hope that it is clear now.

Comment: @PaulFrost Now it is and thanks - your work is very detailed and meticulous but that threw me. I think a generic "B" would have been better in this case.